# No internet at all on new Dell computer Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, internet

Okay, so I just got a new Dell computer.  I installed Ubuntu 18.04 over the Windows 10, and not only does the internet not work, it doesn't even display any network related messages, such as "no networks available."  There is nothing showing in the "Systems and Updates" > "Additional Drivers" section, despite the fact that I mounted the iso file.  There's no Network Manager at all, by appearances.

I put "sudo lspci" and saw a bunch of Intel stuff, and the command "lshw -C network" shows that there's a network controller.  It also says "network UNCLAIMED" if that means anything.  But the short of it is, Ubuntu does know that there is a network card there.

I don't know if this is related, but also the terminal doesn't recognize the command "ifconfig".

In any case, I know nothing about Ubuntu besides what I've searched over the internet the past week, and the only hint I have for this particular problem is something about missing files in /var/log (no idea if that's the real solution) and something about a chipset, except I don't know where to find a chipset name.  Please help!

Edit: Here's a screencap:
[lshw -C network results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWUZm.png)

Comment: What are you calling "internet connection"? Is it a Wi-Fi or what?

Comment: I can't exactly copy/paste, but I'll do something.  Also, as far as internet connection goes, there's nothing in the upper right corner.  Nothing to indicate that there is even a network card at all, even despite the fact that the terminal can see the network card.

Comment: Newer hardware generally requires a newer kernel. Did wireless work with your 18.04 installer? If not, try a 19.10 installer, Test using the "Try Ubuntu" environment...testing hardware is one of its purposes.